# What is it called when your laptop cursor goes wild?

Tags: word-choice

Working on the laptop all day, I want a word for when my cursor (pointer) just keeps going on its own even though my hand is nowhere close to the laptop mouse controls.  Profanity is fine!

Note that I have only witnessed this phenomenon when using the native mousepad or mouse control button on a laptop.  If I plugged in a regular usb mouse this wouldn't happen.  I have not noticed this on tablets yet.  But I have had at least 20 laptops and happened with all of them.

Usage: Coworker - "What is taking so long?"  Me - "F*cking mouse thing, wait a minute."

Would like to have a phrase to replace "F*cking mouse thing."

Comment: Check your USB ports for extra wireless receivers. The most common cause of this problem is coworker pranking.

Comment: For my laptop it is when I am hitting a direction on it for too long.  It then continues in that direction until it is done.

Comment: *Digital drift*? *Arrow anomaly*? *Marker madness*? *Pointer paradoxity*?

Comment: @bib Those are good.  Would like to add angst too.

Comment: Since you are that easy, I moved them to answers.

Comment: PEBCAK maybe. Have you been degaussed lately?

Comment: Added supplement

Comment: How about a roundabout phrase like, “the cat’s away”? The mouse (well, cursor, but so many people mix the terms up) is playing, after all…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your cursor is [malfunctioning](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/malfunctioning).  That's the term I ususally use to describe hardware or software not working correctly.

You could also say it is going [haywire](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/malfunctioning), which is a little bit more slang and has a stronger connotation of wild movement that is unexpected. I would recommend this personally for erratic movements that are inexplicable.

As for profanity?  Too many to list.

Comment: Haywire is a good word but I would like a phrase to convey it.  Right now I call it the "F*cking mouse thing".

Comment: Erratic movement?  Uncontrolled Spasms? Autonomous Mouse Motion? (You did say it happens when you aren't even touching it, after all). You've got a plethora of phrases to choose from.

Comment: @RyeBread I have heard "on the fritz" used for that exact situation, as in: "My mouse/cursor is on the fritz."

Comment: That would also definitely work.

Comment: _Haywire_ is a good word, but ***going*** _haywire_ is a good phrase. Just a thought.

Comment: @called2voyage I thought it was *my cat is on the [Fritz*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz_the_Cat)?

Comment: @bib [More info on "on the fritz"](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-ont4.htm)

Answer (score 4):

You might say your mouse has gone *[feral](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/feral#Adjective)* (“Wild, untamed, especially of domesticated animals having returned to the wild”).

Answer (score 2):

*Digital drift? Arrow anomaly? Marker madness? Pointer paradoxity? Indicator angst*?

SUPPLEMENT

*Twitchy rodent*? *Meandering Mickey*? *Rogue rat*?

Answer (score 0):

Your mouse is bewitched, possessed. It is sleepwalking. (Sorry, no invectives.)

Comment: Your cursor has emancipated itself?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use: "My vermin has gone rabid"